# DispatchGroup is not executing correctly when downloading Firebase Storage Data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a situation where I have a closure that fetches User Data from Firebase, and within it I have another closure that downloads an Image from Firebase Storage.

I need to be able to download the image from Storage before signing in the user. I thought I'd try a DispatchGroup(), but I cannot assign the Image Data to self.photoImage, it always returns nil.

`self.photoImage = UIImage(data: data!)`

This is my first time working with Storage and GroupDispatch(), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var userInfo: User?
    @Published var signedIn: Bool = false
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    let authRef = Auth.auth()
    
    var authHandle : AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    var rootInfoCollection : CollectionReference!
    var userIdRef = ""

    var photoImage: UIImage?
    var downloadImageTask: StorageReference?
    
    var group = DispatchGroup()
    
    func fetchUserData(){
        db.collection("Users").document("\(userIdRef)").getDocument { [self] document, error in
            // Check for error
            if error == nil {
                // Check that this document exists
                if document != nil && document!.exists {
                                        
                    self.userInfo = document.map { (documentSnapshot) -> User in
                        let data = documentSnapshot.data()
                        
                        let uid = data?["uid"] as? UUID ?? UUID()
                        let company = data?["company"] as? String ?? ""
                        let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let admin = data?["admin"] as? Bool ?? false
                        let photoRef = data?["photoRef"] as? String ?? ""
                        
                        self.downloadImageTask = Storage.storage().reference().child(photoRef)
                        
                        return User(uid: uid, company: company, name: name, admin: admin, photoRef: photoRef, photoImage: nil)
                    }
                    
                    group.enter()
                    downloadImageTask?.getData(maxSize: 6 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Got an error fetching data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        } else {
                            self.photoImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                        self.group.leave()
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
                        
                        self.group.wait()
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            if photoImage != nil {
                                print("Photo Image Is Set")
                            }
                            
                            withAnimation {
                                self.signedIn = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The whole structure of your DispatchGroup is wrong, and in any case this is not a situation where DispatchGroup is appropriate or needed.

Comment: I suggest you to go read something on GCD, Ray Wenderlich tutorial is pretty good https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested it, maybe this works for you:

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    @Published var userInfo: User?
    @Published var signedIn: Bool = false

    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    let authRef = Auth.auth()

    var authHandle : AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    var rootInfoCollection : CollectionReference!
    var userIdRef = ""

    var photoImage: UIImage?
    var downloadImageTask: StorageReference?

    var group = DispatchGroup()

    func fetchUserData(){
        db.collection("Users").document("\(userIdRef)").getDocument { [self] document, error in
            // Check for error
            if error == nil {
                // Check that this document exists
                if document != nil && document!.exists {
                                    
                    self.userInfo = document.map { (documentSnapshot) -> User in
                        let data = documentSnapshot.data()
                    
                        let uid = data?["uid"] as? UUID ?? UUID()
                        let company = data?["company"] as? String ?? ""
                        let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let admin = data?["admin"] as? Bool ?? false
                        let photoRef = data?["photoRef"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                        self.downloadImageTask = Storage.storage().reference().child(photoRef)
                    
                        return User(uid: uid, company: company, name: name, admin: admin, photoRef: photoRef, photoImage: nil)
                    }
                
                    group.enter()
                    downloadImageTask?.getData(maxSize: 6 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Got an error fetching data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        } else {
                            self.photoImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                        self.group.leave()
                    }
                    group.notify(queue: .main) { [self] in
                        if photoImage != nil {
                            print("Photo Image Is Set")
                        }
                        
                        withAnimation {
                            self.signedIn = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```